# pthread stack size increase automatically?

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, posix

I'm working on pthread in android NDK that process video data through network.

I meet problem that is 'stack corruption detected : aborted'. So I set -fstack-check in application.mk, and FATAL SIGNAL 11 blabla.. again.

My conclusion in this problem is about stack size.

When I use window thread, its stack size sets 1kb as default, increase automatically.

but, I don't know about pthread.

Is pthread increase stack size automatically?

p.s. I attached this thread to JavaVM.

Comment: pthreads are run by OS threads.  1K is probably not enough to contain the initially-loaded top-of-stack frame. In any case, the OS will be unable to allocate less than one page, (often 4K) for the initial thread stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On stock Android, pthread stacks are allocated at 1MB by default.  (Because of the way the system works, only the parts of the stack that are actually touched get physical pages, so for many threads there's actually only a few KB in use.)

The "stack corruption" message indicates that something has trashed the stack, not that you've run off the end.  One way to encounter this is to write off the end of a stack-allocated array.  It might be useful to [decode the stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314273/get-function-names-from-call-stack/2480465#2480465) you get in the log file and see what method it's in when it fails.

Comment: Thank you! and sorry for late!